# Sitewide http auth interfering with Symfony2 app authentication

Tags: apache, symfony, apache2, http-authentication, symfony-2.3

I have a site under development with the following structure:

```
public_html/
    index.php
    symfony_app/
    other_app/
```

Currently I have the root of the site behind Basic HTTP authentication during the development testing phase. I couldn't figure out why my Symfony2 authentication for a valid user (myusername) was always redirecting to the Symfony login page. In the logs after successful Symfony login

```
security.INFO: User "myusername" has been authenticated successfully [] []
```

I found:

```
security.INFO: Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user "otherusername" [] []
```

..which is the user required by .htpasswd in the root of the site. So it seems that I have an issue with, for lack of a better term, nested http authentication.

Is it possible to have a Symfony app living behind http auth without the two clashing?

Security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        My\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:  ROLE_USER

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: MyUserBundle:User }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
        switch_user: true
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

Comment: can you paste your security.yml ?

Comment: that's what I was thinking: you have `http_basic: ~ ` enabled. It means that the security will listen for hhtp basic headers, and yes, they are present (because of htaccess stuff) and thus, you're anthenticated in symfony2 thru them.

Comment: solution would be to remove the `http_basic: ~` line.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had switched to IP based access control so I didn't test your solution right away, but I just did and I'm afraid it doesn't work. A valid user still can't log in after going through the main http auth.